# unable to send data to MongoDB using spark strucutred streaming

Tags: mongodb, scala, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I followed This [Unable to send data to MongoDB using Kafka-Spark Structured Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55796119/unable-to-send-data-to-mongodb-using-kafka-spark-structured-streaming) to send data from spark structured streaming to mongoDB and I implemented it successfully but there is one issue .
Like when function

```
override def process(record: Row): Unit = {

    val doc: Document = Document(record.prettyJson.trim)
    // lazy opening of MongoDB connection


    ensureMongoDBConnection()
    val result = collection.insertOne(doc)
    if (messageCountAccum != null)
      messageCountAccum.add(1)
  }
```

code is executing without any problem but no data is being send to MongoDB

But if i add a print statement like this

```
override def process(record: Row): Unit = {
    val doc: Document = Document(record.prettyJson.trim)

    // lazy opening of MongoDB connection


    ensureMongoDBConnection()
    val result = collection.insertOne(doc)
    result.foreach(println) //print statement
    if (messageCountAccum != null)
      messageCountAccum.add(1)
  }
```

Data is getting inserted in MongoDB

I don't know why????

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` initializes the writer sink. Without the foreach your dataframe is never calculated.

```
Try this :

val df = // your df here
df.map(r => process(r))
df.count()
```